# Scheduling consecutive tasks from the command line

Tags: command-line, cron, schedule

I have been reading about using 'at' to schedule tasks from the command line based on start time [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/at.1.html).

If I don't know how long tasks will take to complete, what is the best way to schedule consecutive tasks? In this case, I want to run several Torch7 scripts consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can enter multiple commands in a single `at` job, and they will be executed sequentially in the order in which you entered them - for example, using `sleep` to simulate an extended command:

```
$ at now +1 minute
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> logger ": starting first job"; sleep 1m
at> logger ": starting second job"; sleep 1m
at> logger ": staring third job"
at> <EOT>
job 2 at Thu Aug 18 07:58:00 2016
```

results in

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Aug 18 07:58:26 xenial-vm steeldriver: : starting first job
Aug 18 07:59:26 xenial-vm steeldriver: : starting second job
Aug 18 08:00:26 xenial-vm steeldriver: : staring third job
```

Alternatively, you could create a wrapper script for your commands and schedule *that* in `at`